# How to parse multipart/form-data request

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, http

i'am trying to parse multipart/form-data using NODEJS.
I took request content i extracted the keys and values but what i read on spec is that there some stuff to take into consideration because request format maybe different depending on some variables, however what i dont understand is when sending a file i expected format to be raw data but in request content there is XML see code below, here is request content.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCOwgtOPCCdIT78aO       
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fullname"

Jhon Doe
------WebKitFormBoundaryCOwgtOPCCdIT78aO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

JhonDoe1950.
------WebKitFormBoundaryCOwgtOPCCdIT78aO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

Lorem ipsum dolor sit emet.
------WebKitFormBoundaryCOwgtOPCCdIT78aO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="default_profile_picture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����►JFIF☺☺☺☺,☺,��VExifMM♦☺→♣☺>☺♣☺☺(♥☺☻☻‼♥☺☺☺,☺☺,☺��,Photoshop 3.08BIM♦♦☼∟☺Z♥∟☺☻♦��♀�http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTc
zkc9d'?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/' x:xmptk='Image::ExifTool 10.10'>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>

 <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
  xmlns:tiff='http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/'>
  <tiff:ResolutionUnit>2</tiff:ResolutionUnit>
  <tiff:XResolution>300/1</tiff:XResolution>
  <tiff:YResolution>300/1</tiff:YResolution>
 </rdf:Description>

 <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
  xmlns:xmpMM='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/'>
  <xmpMM:DocumentID>adobe:docid:stock:6f982a8a-06c5-42d0-9be7-b5447f4f78e5</xmpMM:DocumentID>
  <xmpMM:InstanceID>xmp.iid:bdb8f439-2357-4602-ba64-ac9d31092b16</xmpMM:InstanceID>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
























<?xpacket end='w'?>��C♣♥♦♦♦♥♣♦♦♦♣♣♣♠☼♂♂ ♀◄☼↕↕◄☼◄◄‼▬∟↨‼¶→§◄◄↑!↑→↔↔▼▼▼‼↨"$"▲$∟▲▼▲��☺h☺h☺☺◄��∟☺☻♥☺☺☺♠☻♦♣♥��@►☻☻☺☻♥♣☺☻♥♦♣◄♠!↕"1AQ‼aq����¶2BRSr��§$3▬#45b��Ct����☺☺?��♥i-���״|6���
K��]'�[���9ҫ�SNM��AE{�λ�����%��$kO��'�p�#��?������♥☼�   |�Hqޤ��▲$�]%�6i���i��aw�↔∟n9Ҭ�]NM☼��I{���״|ƕ→�♫O��]↨�{↔$�[�♥��kZn�▼��c↓�W▲��舖��Y‼�→v,j�u����\���j→���↨9KԈ&��9��Uao�C�{�/׻����7)9I�I��ovπ}�q��[���4�h�h|c���Vn��.[����{�_i;�5\↔V�;�z��Z☼���F�☺◄�n0�§�↨K��z�+_8C�����ed_�|�ɶv�.�I���z��_�|oƶu[▲�E��=�0�)�↨Tq���6�P���q.cu��T��q�"����I§�▬qU���▲�)U��)�Jߔ⌂r,♦�����=�☼P�����eW�?�b�ewU�g   -�(��F@↑�et�+m�')JOd��Yqw◄٫\��ܡ��v;▼��x"<↕▲◄�;4��>C�����[�^�¶Y��]�Fڧ↓�i8�=�^&@�8�^�t↔wQ�J�-̷�E��>�TYWە�fM���d���Y�☺�}��5��>���J/��ժ�fUˤ��~�j7�§��-W麯Ъ��b���j}������☺�����⌂�Ķ����>�����→���O→�C���#��↨����⌂�$x_�→�▬��→�B�����������Ķ����>���↕⌂'
��е_�[-��{-�������,�9�G��/G�/�MG�Z��砨dܤ�&�&�m���6��?+Q��↑�9˶M�W�}��G�|∟5R˿�y���G�w�I$��v%�}��i��O�>�p�♫b���b_ۼ↨Q���!:����dy���%�▬��K�>�T▼b�d�▬�$�Mw2���Ej�↓�☼1�j��i쫱t�+��͗→{��`7�2�▼☼�ޞ�U8���/ܨ{9☻I�X*�Ny�[�→=_��=�rv☺♦��§F�♀�Ghdǭ��o�lF�o"��|����W���J2��O�:@�yL���uR�;�I��o�W��↔��ͺ�NS~��_���q�:�A��u��f�[��r�♣����9
♠+�"��΀?�⧠�E�♦���X☻m�ݬϧ�Bkމ�+�)��XƏ�>��?�↕♣��SVh↑2_������s��j�♥:O�Z�����%�L%���▼∟}��_2�♣s�3����h��"*    �☺d�tWC}j,koC�$�☻=ǹ*�§P�Z�↕�й��☺♦�ɟ�������%�        
��|v�1�㏷�O�D�☺������l��d�6��R�/���►♣{ƹ�3Wt�-��^mm������8@��0���L�1���|�♀►_*umf♣�*p~�B@\���X�+�GS�Q�K�T��_{�_��v@♫7§j��0∟k��Uɪ��������ͽ�&�K*����¶ ��☻-�2�9��r\�7�i��\li�w���'→}k�?Ab�Z�6��ҭ�]§��M�x�I�♫n��ciX�+→��_�ԟ9z_���֡�~v\�rgҲ~Ļ��→�▬?�:<އm�s��ש$�d�∟�(�y�?�B[���▼Z�b���=1�▲��E��Ƚ�(��%�?↨ťV�[��j�'�ȓ�e�e��ž����o�
=�<2��+��_]1�\��◄�c�⓫L���5���G�D��܋�u�J�$����l�vs-�↨�x|?�C[IT�/[��s�♥[��aNk�o♥W��ke]�G�k�Ѥ☺�!;7�BS��E7�12�s�ju�P��q{3�F��R���s^‼�_����ֶ��P��▼��~��\���r^►�?�
74�37R���C�_Zo�c�d�K�♀JR�u�&⌂r=X/�$X�S�Z�▲�U♣�a↔����wL�nr��Z��U��ֻ↓▲����6�ri�=�{��Qͻ����<♂%�R�������+�[=���j��☻��f�⌂vt��72m<��i�z��⌂♦Ht�↔�0→�i��������.�t�(�
&�^EP�☼��;�;�p�%��♠Ǎ?�.�▼�◄-OL��l�e���՚�↓z��L���t�5↓ǫ\|�o�O��m�'�♥��zr�4{�9t�zU�        �k�zJ�I�N2N2Of�s>>���I���.�Y�p���F��cڨOf�3��↕�j���U5ƺⶌb�H�☺��0���U]\l�KiFKtȆ�
Y→Zr�k�������D�qm4�Of�q�☺�)�J1NRod�{-�∟�֗�щ˦�ұ���⌂/��☺[yBҾ���6��FS���g޿^�i↑♥:*���M0���1���>�▼�M�r2¶m�k��W�^�I�♫☼↕��Z�e��ѫ1.��g��}$♠�����t%]�{J2\�0☻O��Jy���m
��b���j}����▬H♥G]Ӫ�t�p���[�_vK��▬U▬��ٍ|:▬�'↓/♠y}�e)(�9I��K�e�º∟t�<��Ṟu�᯺�,�∟>*����芎ek��◄}��e{(�2q�q�{4�4π▲��[��^5►��d�b�Yn�ZuZV�V↔\�+y��I��x">P4'�G�LXo}Q�
�)}x.�Z���☻a��:Ij�◄��c����D�☻!�::i���dE{��d<☻��⌂�<Z?�eCk��E����⌂�.+�8���-C♫▼�X��K�R⌂�~�,t8⌂N���׍�V�ֵ�§���,�F0���)(�ؒ�2�q��(N*Q�jI�4��ˈ4�i�����o�S}�}��ÞJx▼��
�tu♀�⌂)[�E���⌂�{�∟↑�]wU*��g     ��▬�Mx§�↨p�M�#↔JxS|�k��?G�;�☼��]'�3��侗�♂ꯏ�H���Ҵ���;ۍ����e��♫�嚵�#!J↑P|�c��/G�,�k���UP�!♦�b��/♥ ♀.����V�3�i�FKtׁ�f2�    T��)
$�rG�▲��+`ձ޹&�}�4�]5F��↑W♦�c§�K��☺�v:}hr~♠�M=�ـ�od�f�8�u���▲�♠6B3[I→�c�<��^��=�ǔ�˪���p�▬�F@♥♂+���y��‼�k�K⌂C<�   ��E�►♥(�r��l��3⌂^[z◄�]p�Տ?‼0♥   U\�`�▲4▼c�0x�‼�▼>�?�‼�ѧ�‼�ѧ��}X�3�↓�h.�&g→��d◄���
------WebKitFormBoundaryCOwgtOPCCdIT78aO--
```

How can i extract the file data (file data above is PNG image) and turn it into a file in my server?

Comment: You have binary data and it cannot be raw.  A request/response is HTML format and binary character have to be escaped or put in a MIME attachment.  See following for a description of MIME : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  To get image your have to extract the binary jpg from the mime attachment.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: An image has an ASCII header and you can clearly see "Photoshop 3.08BIM" which means the image is raw.  You need to parse the body of the response and extract the data starting two lines after image/jpeg and then take all the bytes until the new line and save into a file.  Your have HTML (not XML).  You do not have any NODES so the library NODEJS will not work.  You simply have mixture of text and binary. So  I would split the data on "\n--" which is the new line followed by two dashes which separate the MIME attachments.

Comment: Then read the three lines before the image.  The first 3 lines will tell you the type of message so you can located the which attachments are images.  The fourth line is the image.